# The image "http://localhost/KVL/showgraph" cannot be displayed because it contains errors - Jpgraph

Tags: php, jpgraph

I am using PHP Jpgraph library to create a graph from arrays generated from a mysql query.

I have written this php code:

```
require_once('jpgraph/src/jpgraph.php');
require_once('jpgraph/src/jpgraph_bar.php'); 

foreach ($results as $key => $value){

$data[] = $value['num_rows'];//$data = array(740,902,647,208);
$data1[] = $value['department_name'];//$data1 = array('Epi', 'Dss', 'Bio', 'Clin');


}

 $graph = new Graph(450,200,"auto");
 $graph->SetScale("textlin");
 $graph->img->SetMargin(40,30,40,40);

 $graph->SetShadow();

  $graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels($data1);

  $bplot = new BarPlot($data);
  $bplot->SetFillColor("lightgreen"); 
  $bplot->value->Show();
  $bplot->value->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_BOLD);
  $bplot->value->SetAngle(45);
  $bplot->value->SetColor("black","navy");

  $graph->Add($bplot);
  $graph->Stroke();
```

I expect a bargraph generated by jpgraph. However, i get a blank page with a message "The image 'http://localhost/KVL/showgraph" cannot be displayed because it contains errors. I have run `php -m` on my terminal and can see that GD extension is installed. I am running `php 7.2`.

Comment: The code you presented works just fine and produces the bar graph as expected. You are probably getting errors somewhere before this code is called which produces output and cause the creation and display of the graph to fail. Does it fail if you remove all of the database interaction and simply use hard coded arrays for your data like this `$data  = [740,902,647,208];
$data1 = ['Epi', 'Dss', 'Bio', 'Clin'];`?

Comment: It works when i use hard coded arrays but does not work when i use database derived arrays

Comment: Then the problem is not related to the graphing portion at all. Please [edit] your question and include the code that you are using to retrieve the values that you want to graph. Also, turn on error reporting `ini_set('display_errors','1');ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');error_reporting(E_ALL);` so you will be able to see any errors that may be thrown.

Comment: I have realized the problem was being caused by array indexing. After doing a `print_r` of the arrays, they were rendering as `Array( [0] => Array([0] => 740)[1] => Array([0] => 902)[2] => Array([0] => 647)[3] => Array([0] => 208))`.  I solved this by re-indexing the arrays and the graph worked.Thanks